# CSS Focus actions on fieldset not functioning?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to create an effect where you click on fieldset/inside of the div a few buttons with an opacity bg and blur effect pops up inside of it. So far I've been able to create the effect of a box opening up but it only works when you click on input.

I'd like to change it so it works on fieldset.focus-actions..... but when I click on the fieldset nothing occurs.

http://jsfiddle.net/s5j4zLb9/

```
fieldset.focus-actions:focus + .submit{
  display: block;
}
```

If it's impossible to set focus on fieldset, is there any other way I can make a dialog box or a few buttons pop up specifically inside my selected element when mouse onClick happens?

Comment: Why is your `<fieldset>` not inside your `<form>`, and, for some reason, being opened before your `<form>`'s opening tag and being closed before the `<form>`'s closing tag? That HTML is invalid. JavaScript, HTML and CSS work far better, and more reliably, using *valid* HTML.

Comment: fieldsets cannot receive focus.  Only input elements, anchors, and buttons can receive focus... but you can't put an input or button inside an anchor.

Comment: what a mess. You could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/s5j4zLb9/1/

Comment: Thank you Nico O, greatly appreciate it! I'm a novice so I'm still learning a lot.

Comment: Sorry if i was a bit harsh @Steve Gates. We are all here to learn. Have fun :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a CSS only solution - You can add a `tabindex` attribute to the form and then target the child

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/david321312312231/s5j4zLb9/2/

CSS

```
form:focus > .submit{
  display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="message-form" action="#" method="post" tabindex="1">
```

a jQuery solution would be

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/david321312312231/s5j4zLb9/3/

```
// this is when the div is on focus
$( "#disp" ).focus(function() {
  $('.submit').css('display','block');
});
// this is when the form is on focus
$( "form" ).focus(function() {
  $('.submit').css('display','block');
});
```